# How do I beat the Bonefin Galaxy Boss?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy

There's a giant fish named Kingfin in the Bonefin galaxy of *Super Mario Galaxy*.

How the heck do I beat him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two turtleshells in that level, a green and a red one.  Use the turtleshells to swim towards him, and once you're within strinking distance, do a 'spin' attack so that you throw the turtleshell.

It takes 5 hits to defeat him.

After the first hit, he releases homing piranhas that come after you.  Dodge these by making quick turns.  There is also a power mushroom that gives you 6 health.

Comment: if you're just asking to seed questions on the site, i think it would be nice to wait at least 24 hours or so before providing the answer yourself, to give someone else the opportunity to answer and get some rep

Comment: @Kip I'm not. I was playing the Bonefin galaxy last night and couldn't seem to beat him and posted the question.  After beating him, I posted the answer.